# Get touch location for appwidget

Tags: android, android-appwidget

When a user clicks on my appwidget, the widget's configuration activity is opened up.  So far that has suited my needs.

Now I'd like to add the ability to perform a special action (e.g. a widget refresh) when the user touches a particular feature or area on the widget, rather than open up the configuration activity.

Is there any way to do that?  Even if it's just a case of detecting whether the touch was in the left half of the widget, for example, that would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(...);
        ...
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, myIntent, 0);
        remoteViewsFive.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imgRefresh, pendingIntent);
```

Like this, imgRefresh is your ImageView with refresh icon (for example). You should define an Intent then create a PendingIntent that set on view

A easy solution to do what you want it's use a transparent png in imgRefresh

Comment: Ah OK, I think I get it.  This seems to be very similar what what google put into my appwidget code (I started with their "hello world" example and went from there) to open up the config activity, with `R.id.imgRefresh` being `R.id.widget` (the whole widget).  So if I have a subelement within my widget (e.g. a transparent png in an `ImageView` if I don't want a visible 'button') then I just do something similar but passing the ID for that into `setOnClickPendingIntent()`.  I'll give it a whirl, after brushing up on `PendingIntent`.